# Bulma input validation

Tags: bulma

Is there any simple way for form validation in Bulma? I thought simple HTML5 input validation (`input step="any" type="number"`),  might work, but it is ignored by Bulma. I saw some JS libraries for form validation which are compatible with Bulma, but isn't there an easier way? Maybe with `oninvalid()` event add somehow `is-danger` style and change back if there is no error?

```html
<form method="post">

    <div class="field is-horizontal">
        <div class="field-label is-normal">
            <label class="label" for="price">
            Price
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="field-body">
            <div class="field">
                <div class="control">
                    <input class="input" id="price" min="1" name="price" placeholder="Price" step="any" type="number"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="field is-horizontal">
        <div class="field-label is-normal">
            <label class="label" for="quantity">
            Quantity
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="field-body">
            <div class="field">
                <div class="control">
                    <input class="input" id="quantity" name="quantity" placeholder="Quantity" type="number"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="field is-horizontal">
        <div class="field-label">
            <!-- Left empty for spacing -->
        </div>
        <div class="field-body">
            <div class="field">
                <div class="control">
                    <input class="button is-success is-outlined" name="submitSave" type="submit" value="Save"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Without JavaScript there is no way to change a CSS .class selector.

In your case you could use the pseudo class invalid to get the wished result with this simple piece of code:

```
.input:invalid {
    border-color: #f14668; /* -> is-danger */
}
```